# Typescript doesnt infer type even if field "type" is const

Tags: typescript

I have a method `request` that takes a message with a type and returns an answer with the same type. The actual message and answer should be inferred by typescript. However, for some reason it doesn't work:

```js
export type Message =
  { type: 'auth', user: string, password: string } |
  { type: 'getData'}

export type Answer = 
  { type: 'auth', success: boolean } |
  { type: 'getData', someData: any}

export type MessageType = Message["type"]
export type ExcludeTypeField<A> = { [K in Exclude<keyof A, "type">]: A[K] }
export type ExtractParameters<A, T> = ExcludeTypeField<Extract<A, { type: T }>>
export type GetForType<A, T> = Extract<A, { type: T }>

// This works
function request<T extends MessageType, K = GetForType< Answer, T >>(
  type: T,
  payload: ExtractParameters<Message, T>
) {

  return new Promise<K>((resolve, reject) => {
    // implementation
    resolve({} as K)
  }) // .then(val is of type K)
}

// But this does not :(
function request2<T extends MessageType, K = GetForType< Answer, T >>(
  payload: Message
) {

  return new Promise<K>(() => {
    // implementation
  }) // .then(val is of type Answer)
}

request('auth', {user: '123', password: '123'}).then(val => {}) // correct
request2({type: 'auth', user: '123', password: '123'}).then(val => {}) // Answer instead of { type: 'auth', success: boolean}
```

How can I make it work so that it also works with the `request2` function?

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=126&pln=1&pc=1#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-AMDJ8mSNIrjKY5qmzhpK5aR4jZ6a23HuGIghJPIHG3Jyfg2aJwRhBE2AxHEiTJFYQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the type of your `request2` arguments from `payload: Message` to `payload: Message & {type: T}`.

If `T` doesn't appear anywhere in your function's arguments, then how does typescript know what `T` is when you call the function?  It would be `unknown` but here it becomes `MessageType` because of the `extends` statement.

By typing `payload` as `Message & {type: T}`, the type `T` for each function call will be the type of `payload.type`.